# Dropdownlist selectedindexchanged not firing

Tags: asp.net

I have `dropdownlist` with some data provided by the page load with calling to a server-side function. On that `dropdownlist` `selectedindexchanged` event, I do need to call to get the value of selected index without `autopostback`. it works only when `autopostback` is set to true.

Answer (score 1):

without autopost back you can't call selectedindexchanged event. If you dont want to refresh the page you can use UpdatePanel or You can use Ajax call.

Comment: i don't want to refresh the page on that  event.

Comment: Use dropdownlist inside UpdatePanel With autopostback property of dropdownlist .

Comment: Welcome Darshana Sandaruwa .-Please upvote my answer.